# Graphql query resolvers split into seperate lamdas

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, serverless

I am writing a serverless app using aws lambdas. we are using apollo graphql for single endpoint. graphql endpoint run in one single lamda, how can i split graphql query mutation resolvers into seperate lamda functions, like in graphcool and aws app-sync.

Answer (score 0):

AWS AppSync has the concept of Datasources which can be individual Lambda functions (or you can use DynamoDB tables or Elasticsearch domains). In your GraphQL schema you would then attach a resolver to a field (like a query or mutation) and this resolver would invoke the Lambda datasource. AppSync lets you do this as a single Lambda invocation or "BatchInvoke" for having the Lambda hit multiple resources and return a LIST.

The resolver template (written in Velocity Template Language) is fairly straightforward to send your GraphQL request on through to Lambda, and adding this is a drop down selection from the samples in the console:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": $util.toJson($context.arguments)
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html

Comment: yes , i already checked the AWS AppSync . but we can't use app-sync since it's only in preview version. what i need is workflow same like that.  but using only serverless and AWS lambda service. we can't use graphcool either. Currently we are using a second tier of lambda functions which are called from resolvers using aws sdk.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the only way to do it on Apollo is to call your Lambdas by their URIs. The good about this is that you can cache their responses. The bad part is that you can't have a pure GraphQL environment.